# c++ wrapper for c file with same name

Tags: c++, wrapper

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to create a program.  The program makes use of a c code with a c++ wrapper, both c and c++ files have the same name.  The files are para_gpio.c para_gpio.cpp and para_gpio.h, both c and c++ include the line #inlcude para_gpio.h.

These files compile without a problem under ubuntu using the GCC compiler, i don't know why VS has a problem?

```
Error List 
Warning 1   warning : Failure to find: para_gpio.c C:\Users\smattu\Documents\VisualGDB\LinuxProject1\LinuxProject1\EXEC LinuxProject1
Warning 2   warning : overriding commands for target `Debug/para_gpio.o'    C:\Users\smattu\Documents\VisualGDB\LinuxProject1\LinuxProject1\Makefile    LinuxProject1
Warning 3   warning : ignoring old commands for target `Debug/para_gpio.o'  C:\Users\smattu\Documents\VisualGDB\LinuxProject1\LinuxProject1\Makefile    LinuxProject1
Error   4   error : Command-line action failed  C:\Users\smattu\Documents\VisualGDB\LinuxProject1\LinuxProject1\VisualGDB   LinuxProject1
Error   5   error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Sysprogs\VisualGDB\\VisualGDB.exe" /rebuild "C:\Users\smattu\Documents\VisualGDB\LinuxProject1\LinuxProject1\LinuxProject1.vcxproj" "/solution:C:\Users\smattu\Documents\VisualGDB\LinuxProject1\LinuxProject1.sln" "/config:Debug" "/platform:Win32"" exited with code 1.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets   43  5   LinuxProject1
```

I think this halts the build

```
make: *** No rule to make target `para_gpio.c', needed by `Debug/para_gpio.o'.  Stop.
```

After the suggestion in renaming, the warning/error has been been reduced to 3

Warning 1   warning : Failure to find: para_gpio.c  C:\Users\smattu\Documents\VisualGDB\LinuxProject1\LinuxProject1\EXEC    LinuxProject1
Error   2   error : Command-line action failed  C:\Users\smattu\Documents\VisualGDB\LinuxProject1\LinuxProject1\VisualGDB   LinuxProject1
Error   3   error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Sysprogs\VisualGDB\VisualGDB.exe" /rebuild "C:\Users\smattu\Documents\VisualGDB\LinuxProject1\LinuxProject1\LinuxProject1.vcxproj" "/solution:C:\Users\smattu\Documents\VisualGDB\LinuxProject1\LinuxProject1.sln" "/config:Debug" "/platform:Win32"" exited with code 1.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets   43  5   LinuxProject1

with warning 1 i have tried removing (and replacing) the para_gpio.c from the source directory and the warning remains constant. It looks like VS can't see that file although i added it through the solution explorer.

Steve

Comment: Is object file name same for both? What problem exactly?

Comment: What problem does VS have?

Comment: It has 3 warnings and 2 errors, these all disappear when the above files are removed.Warning                                       1 warning : Failure to find: para_gpio.c                   2 warning : overriding commands for target `Debug/para_gpio.o'  3 warning : ignoring old commands for target `Debug/para_gpio.o'
4 error : Command-line action failed 
5 error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Sysprogs\VisualGDB\\VisualGDB.exe" /rebuild "C:\Users\smattu\Documents\VisualGDB\LinuxProject1\

Comment: Isn't renaming it to something different a solution for you?